# NavigationStack Type '() -> ()' cannot conform to 'View'

Tags: swiftui, xcode14

I am building a simple Sign Up and Login user flow with SwiftUI in Xcode 14. I am attempting to use the `NavigationStack` struct, however I am receiving the error below.

I am seeking to correct this code, or to implement another non-deprecated way of using navigation in SwiftUI to control different application views. I would hope to expand on this further by creating additional views (forgot password, login with email link, etc).

```swift
import SwiftUI

enum Route : Hashable {
  case login
  case signup
  case app
}

@main
struct MyApp: App {
  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
      NavigationStack {
        ContentView()                                       // Type '() -> ()' cannot conform to 'View'
          .navigationDestination(for: Route.self) {         // Type '() -> ()' cannot conform to 'View'
            route in {
              switch route {
              case .login:
                Text("Login")
              case .signup:
                Text("Sign Up")
              }
            }
          }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @NiravD - if I remove `route in {}`, I get this error: `Cannot find 'route' in scope`.  If you want to provide a full working code solution I would accept as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have added extra `{` after `route in` and because of this `Xcode` added `}` as well. So remove this extra start `{` and end `}`. Now after fixing this in your switch case you missed handling of `app` case because of this you will get **`Switch must be exhaustive`** error. To fix this add `app` case or `default` case as well in your switch. After fixing both issues your code will look like this.

```
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationStack {
                ContentView()
                    .navigationDestination(for: Route.self) { route in
                        switch route {
                        case .login:
                            Text("Login")
                        case .signup:
                            Text("Sign Up")
                        case .app:
                            Text("App")
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```